# Incorporating a C++ namespace with header/source separation

Tags: c++, static-libraries, directory-structure, separation-of-concerns

In a project of C++ utility functions I am hand rolling for personal use, I am grouping functions for parts of the library in two files. So for a `digitmanip` toolset there's I am separating the source and header code in this manner:

```
src/digitmanip.cpp -> include/digitmanip.hpp (functions for manipulating numbers and their digits)
src/add.cpp -> include/add.hpp (a set of adding functions for containers, varargs, etc...)
```

This structure I've used before and works well, but I would like to have all of the functions under a `namespace libname`. Can I keep the source/header separation the same while keeping everything under the same namespace?

Comment: What problem specifically do you encounter when trying to do this? If you simply wrap all declarations that should be in `libname` with `namespace libname { /*...*/ }` everywhere and qualify uses outside these declarations with `libname::` it should work typically work without issue. Namespaces are orthogonal to separation into translation units and header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [C++ namespaces are additive](https://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/35506/). So you can extend any namespace in any file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add functions and types to namespaces anywhere you want - they are additive. you can open and close a namespace as many times as you need/want, to add things to it.